# Dropping rows if values from a column do not meet the requirements in another column

Tags: python, pandas

So lets say I have this dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame({'ID': [1001,4003,1001, 4003, 7000, 7000], 
            'col_2': ['3', '8', '2', '1','7','9'], 
            'col_3': ['Steak','Chicken','Chicken','Steak','Chicken','Chicken']})
```

I want to create 3 data frames.
The first two would be a data frame for each ID that had Chicken. The second would be for all the IDs that had beef. That is easy enough:

```
dfsteak = df[~(df['col_3'] != 'Steak')]
dfchicken =  df[~(df['col_3'] != 'Chicken')]
```

But for the third, I want to drop any row if an ID does not have Chicken one time, and Steak another. So in this example DF that would be ID 7000, who ordered only Chicken. But how would I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `filter` with `any`

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x : ((x['col_3']=='Steak').any())&((x['col_3']=='Chicken').any()))
Out[14]: 
     ID col_2    col_3
0  1001     3    Steak
1  4003     8  Chicken
2  1001     2  Chicken
3  4003     1    Steak
```

To filter out ID 7000

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x : ~((x['col_3']=='Steak').any())&((x['col_3']=='Chicken').any()))
Out[16]: 
     ID col_2    col_3
4  7000     7  Chicken
5  7000     9  Chicken
```

Comment: 25% faster:

`f = lambda x : ((x == 'Steak').any())&((x == 'Chicken').any())
df.groupby('ID')['col_3'].filter(f)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one intuitive way. The idea is to create a series aggregating `col_3` to a `set` by `ID`.

Then filter for when a mapped `set` is *not* a superset of `{'Steak', 'Chicken'}`.

```
s = df.groupby('ID')['col_3'].apply(set)
df = df[~(df['ID'].map(s) >= {'Steak', 'Chicken'})]

print(df)

     ID col_2    col_3
4  7000     7  Chicken
5  7000     9  Chicken
```

Comment: Very interesting solution. It's also faster than `filter()`, kind of surprising.

Comment: @liliscent, Yep, the problem with `filter` is when it's used with an inefficient `lambda` function. Multiple traversals which aren't necessary when you're done with the one-off cost of building `s`.